# How to search for files that e.g. contain one word, but not another one, in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-search

I am looking for a quick way to perform complicated text search within VSCode.

Some examples:

- Multiple keywords (file contains both `apple` and `orange` anywhere in the text file)
- Negative keywords (file contains `apple` but not `cherry` anywhere in the text document)

VSCode does an excellent job of providing quick results but only allows for single keywords. Regular expression doesn't solve the problem because the keywords in any order.

On the mainframe this is done when you perform a search (global find) it presents a list files that match your keyword result. You then can perform another search, searching just the files from your previous search results. Using technique you can stack multiple keyword search on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Agent Ransack https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/ will do that.

There's a free version and a paid version - I think the free version will do what you need.

You'll have to learn how to use regular expressions (Google it).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Visual Studio Code PowerShell terminal. Open up the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>.

Both `apple` and `orange` (long hand):

```
get-childitem -recurse | where-object {$_ | select-string 'apple'} | where-object {$_ | select-string 'orange'} | select fullname
```

Or simply (shorthand):

```
ls -r | ?{$_ | sls 'apple'} | ?{$_ | sls 'orange'} | select fullname
```

`apple` but not `cherry` (shorthand):

```
ls -r | ?{$_ | sls 'apple'} | ?{-not($_ | sls 'cherry')} | select fullname
```

Results should look something like this. You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left mouse button</kbd> `C:\temp\apple.txt` to open the file

```
FullName
--------
C:\Temp\apple.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normally achievable with just regexes. E.g. with [grepWin](https://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html) or any tool supporting modern regex engines you can use:

```
\A(?!.*\bcherry\b).*\bapple\b
```

Which basically starts matching at the start of the whole string (`\A`) and then ensures no `cherry` word until the end of string with negative lookahead, then it matches `apple` as a requirement. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956149/grepwin-find-this-but-not-that-search-for-a-page-that-has-a-string-but-not-ano) for full explantation.

Visual Studio Code unfortunately currently throws an error when using this regex in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> search due to `\A`. I reported it as an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/188547).

The only alternative in VSCode itself without help of any shells seems to be using [Reverse Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanishSarwar.reverse-search) extension, but that only supports non-matching searching from what I see, no way to combine it with regular search.